# import products in each category in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, import

As per my client client request, we need to import all the products in magento each category. Is this possible to do that in magento 1.9 version?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following tutorial about export and import products with specific categories:

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-products.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Magmi? You can import products to multiple categories putting in file category tree levels. Even if categories are missing, you can do this and they will be created on a fly.